# Do I have to cite my own paper?

Tags: publications, citations, self-citation

I wrote a paper in which I mentioned all citations for definitions that are not mine, and did not cite my previous paper's definition or my supervisor's previous papers as both of us are authors.

My supervisor got really angry on me for this. Did I deserve it?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you showed the manuscript without those citations to your supervisir *before* submitting it to a journal, so that you had the opportunity to add the citations before submission?

Comment: One more reason to cite your previous work, is to make it easier to read. When you use some definition, it's very handy how was the definition created.

Comment: I properly understood the value of citiations when I got from nearly zero AI knowledge, to understanding GPT-2, by following citations backwards. If you are referring to work that was done earlier, please cite it so readers can find it!

Comment: Interested readers will want to read those papers to understand the background.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you do need to cite your own past work. Not doing so is considered to be self-plagiarism. While ethically self-plagiarism might not be as bad as plagiarizing someone’s else work, it is still not okay.

Self-plagiarism misleads the reader as it presents previously published work as new and original. Academic readers expect that all uncited material is either common knowledge or a novel idea. By not citing your previous work, you are undermining the integrity of academia.

Next, self-plagiarism is bad because publishers (including academic ones) sometimes have a copyright on your previously published work. While you are still an author you are no longer allowed to use the previous work willy-nilly. However, this also depends on what copyright agreement you have and nature of the self-plagiarism (e.g. paraphrasing old work would not violate it).

Lastly there is no reason not to cite yourself. Self-citations still improve your citation count. You should not do it unnecessarily, because overly self-citing is also frown upon, e.g., even when the previous work is not much relevant. However, when there is a legitimate reason to self-cite, there is no reason not to do it.

Comment: *self-plagiarism bad because publishers […] have a copyright on your previously published work* – This paragraph is misleading about the reach of copyright. Copyright only applies if you reproduce something verbatim or close to verbatim – which should you rarely ever do in most disciplines anyway. For example, I could remove all my citations from all my publications without committing a single breach of copyright. (Mind that for verbatim quotes, citations can help copyright-wise.) Also, most modern copyright agreements are not wholesale transfers of copyright anymore.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft thanks for the comment I tried to clarify my answer

Comment: Self plagiarism is repeated publication of the same material.  It's still plagiarism even if the previous publication is cited.

Comment: Publishers being assigned copyright in an academic paper is rare (depending a bit on field I guess). I don’t think I’ve assigned copyright for over a decade.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist but if the prior work is cited, wouldn't it be clear to readers that the author is not trying to pass this as something new? Would it be self-plagiarism if I put my paper on two websites (e.g., arXiv and my personal website)? And which good journal wouldn't reject publishing the same idea even if it's cited?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist but my understanding is OP is talking about single definition. I don’t know how it works in your field, but in my field if you came up with some definition in previous paper (maybe theoretical paper) and then you write second paper (maybe empirically testing the previous theory with some coauthors) then you are supposed to cite the definition in your theoretical paper and nobody considers that plagiarism then. However, if you do not cite it, reader of the new (empirical) paper might think that the definition is also novel and then it would be case of self plagiarism

Comment: Of course trying to pass (essentially) the same paper to two separate journals would be self plagiarism no matter whether first is cited or not

Comment: "Next, self-plagiarism is bad because publishers (including academic ones) have a copyright on your previously published work."
Not always. If you publish open-access it is common that you (the author) retain the copyright. Instead, you only grant a (non-revokable) license to the publisher to reproduce it.

Comment: @justhalf In academia, putting things on your personal website is not considered publication, so it is not self plagiarism.

Comment: @1muflon1 Sure, you can restate a definition with a citation to the source.  A definition isn't really the "material" part of a publication.

Comment: @1muflon1 In the current version I still think the third paragraph (about copyright) is misleading. Personally, I'd suggest removing it entirely, and I think the answer would be better off for it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Your comment that copyright only applies if you reproduce something close to verbatim is *usually* true in academic writing because facts cannot be protected by copyright. However please note that it is considerably more nuanced in any work where facts do not predominate (which can include certain types of academic analysis). When something is at stake, it is generally wise to consult with an intellectual property attorney. Nothing I say on stackechange should ever be interpreted as legal advice.

Answer (score 44):

It appears that you mistakenly assume that citations are only about avoiding plagiarism.
However, the main purpose of citations is to document the provenance of ideas, evidence, etc.
If done properly, this automatically wards you against any accusation of plagiarism, but that is only a side effect.
In most papers, you can leave out a considerable portion of citations without introducing any plagiarism (it would still not be a good idea though).

If you treat citations as documenting provenance, it is clear that it shouldn’t matter who authored the work you cite: Ideally, you cite your own work if and only if you would also cite it if authored by somebody else.

Typically, authors tend to overdo self-citations, but you can also underdo them.
Usually this is just bad citing, but at worst it can also be regarded as self-plagiarism, i.e., selling your own old work as new work.

Answer (score 14):

Your choice to cite a paper should not depend on who wrote the paper.  It does not matter if you wrote it, your supervisor wrote it, or a [nazi](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84829/how-does-it-affect-the-treatment-of-a-mathematicians-results-if-that-mathemati) wrote it. Cite all sources you use.  Where feasible, cite other relevant sources.

Do not cite your own work if it's not relevant.

I cannot think of any situation where it would be appropriate to be angry about citations.

Comment: This is the best answer